# How to merge array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge same array id into 1 array and and sum pageview using PHP. Please Help me.

Code

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17088
            [PageView] => 5575
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17088
            [PageView] => 4338
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1121
            [PageView] => 3922
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11397
            [PageView] => 2625
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9638
            [PageView] => 2541
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11397
            [PageView] => 2377
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1121
            [PageView] => 10
        )
)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17088
            [PageView] => 9913
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1121
            [PageView] => 3932
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11397
            [PageView] => 5002
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9638
            [PageView] => 2541
        )
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Um .... `array_merge()`  usually works.  I know it's got one of those hard names to figure out.  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff0208bc45af55549a187b174e6c1432874131f5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

foreach ($array as $row)
  $grouped[$row['id']] += $row['PageView'];

print_r($grouped);
```

Comment: Really smart answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic,

```
$test = [1=> ['id'=>10, 'sum'=>10],['id'=>12, 'sum'=>10],['id'=>10, 'sum'=>10]];

    merge($test);
function merge($array) 
{
    $tempArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(array_key_exists($value['id'],$tempArray)) {
           $tempArray[$value['id']]['sum'] = $tempArray[$value['id']]['sum'] +  $value['sum'];
        } else {
            $tempArray[$value['id']] = $value;
        }
    }
    print "<pre>"; print_r($tempArray); exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the array and sum if the key already exist.
I make an associative array on the id which makes it easy to sum in the loop.
If you want an indexed array you can use array_values after the loop.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    if(isset($new[$sub['id']])){
        $new[$sub['id']]['PageView'] = $new[$sub['id']]['PageView'] + $sub['PageView'];
    }else{
        $new[$sub['id']] = $sub;
    }

}
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [17088]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "17088"
    ["PageView"]=>
    int(9913)
  }
  [1121]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1121"
    ["PageView"]=>
    int(3932)
  }
  [11397]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "11397"
    ["PageView"]=>
    int(5002)
  }
  [9638]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "9638"
    ["PageView"]=>
    string(4) "2541"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/W3Afa

Answer (score 0):

Try This code-

This is your array -

```
$a = array(0=>array('id' => 17088,'PageView' => 5575),1=>array('id' => 17088,'PageView' => 4338),2=>array('id' => 1121,'PageView' => 3922),3=>array('id' => 11397,'PageView' => 2625),4=>array('id' => 9638,'PageView' => 2541),5=>array('id' => 11397,'PageView' => 2377),6=>array('id' => 1121,'PageView' => 10));

    $b=array();

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($b[$value['id']]) && count($b[$value['id']])){
            $b[$value['id']]['PageView']=$b[$value['id']]['PageView']+$value['PageView'];
        }else{
            $b[$value['id']]['id']=$value['id'];
            $b[$value['id']]['PageView']=$value['PageView'];
        }
    }

    print_r($b);
```

Output -

```
Array
(
    [17088] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17088
            [PageView] => 9913
        )

    [1121] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1121
            [PageView] => 3932
        )

    [11397] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11397
            [PageView] => 5002
        )

    [9638] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9638
            [PageView] => 2541
        )

)
```